# Is it possible to set a default value for field A based on the value of field B in the same table?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a table with an autonumber field. I have a second field where on insert I want it to take the generated number for the autonumber field and prefix it with 'S'. How can I do this? Can I put some kind of expression in the default value specification?

Comment: Use of a "default" implies that the value in either column can changed after insertion - directly or indirectly. Is that something you need to do? Do you understand that identity columns can have gaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a (`PERSISTED`) computed column:

```sql
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable ADD PrefixedAutoNumber AS CONCAT('S',AutoNumber) PERSISTED;
```

Then you don't need to `INSERT` it, or anything else, it'll have simply have the value of your `AutoNumber` column prefixed with an `'S'`. Persisting the column means you can add it to indexes, which'll help for performance if you'll going to be using the column for `WHERE` clauses or `JOIN`s.

If it is, however, purely for display/presentation purposes, and will never be used in the `WHERE`/`ON` then you don't need to persist the column.